# Extracting just a part of Subfolder name from filepath

Tags: excel

I have a list of filepath names and wish to extract just **part** of the subfolder names.

For Example: C:\Users\zatin.dharmapuri\Desktop\Reviews\01 Sprint **1**\08 Address Result Popup Dialog Review_Implemented 1.0.xlsx

In the above example, I need to extract **only** the Sprint numbers from the filepath. These numbers can be of 2 digits too.

What I have is a function that serves another requirement by giving me the file name which falls after the last " \ "

```
=IF(RawData!B1="","",MID(RawData!G1,FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(RawData!G1,"\","*",LEN(RawData!G1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(RawData!G1,"\",""))))+1,LEN(RawData!G1)))
```

Is there a function to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in, say **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("Sprint ",A1)+7,2),"\","")
```

This will return either one or two digit Sprint numbers *(as text)*:

[image]

If you require the result as a **number**, then use:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("Sprint ",A1)+7,2),"\","")
```

Comment: That worked great! I have a related follow up question. From the provided file path and the function provided in my question. I manage to get the numeric value 08 which follows the sprint num\. But when I try using the INDEX MATCH formula with the value it throws up an error as the MATCH formula is not recognizing 08 with 8. I checked the cell format, all good on that end. When I physically enter 08 the INDEX MATCH formula works fine. Any solutions to it?

Comment: @ZatinDharmapuri  It may be the difference between **08** as *Text* and **08** as a *Number*

Comment: I don't see how I can get that working. Can you help me with a formula that fetches numbers as numeric values from the file name? All file names are prefixed with a number that ranges from 01 to 700.

Comment: I guess I got it to work by using this formula
=IF(A1="","",SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&A1,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW($1:$25),1))* ROW($1:$25),0),ROW($1:$25))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$25)/10))

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you need the data that occurs between the name "Sprint" in the folder path and the next folder/file in the path. If the text "Sprint" is only going to show up once in your file paths, you can just do

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("Sprint",A1)+LEN("Sprint"),FIND("\",A1,FIND("Sprint",A1))-FIND("Sprint",A1)-LEN("Sprint")))
```

This finds a starting point of the first character after "Sprint" in your data, then pulls the amount of characters up to the first instance of "\" after "Sprint". The FIND function is case sensitive and searches for an exact string. If your data isn't fully consistent like that, it can be replaced with the SEARCH function, which is not case sensitive and allows wildcard queries.

Comment: Thanks and I appreciate your time. I for now am using Gary's formula but I can use your function with a little modification for other purposes. For that, I will first try understanding the functions used in your formula.